# SQL Server Inner Join Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

What I am working on is I have to grab data from 4 different tables. The only problem I have is the "where" clause as well as the last join. I need to know what I did wrong Thank you

```
DECLARE @Year INT
SET @Year = 2014

SELECT c.program_id
    ,d.dealer_id
    ,a.account_no
    ,a.vin
    ,b.first_name
    ,b.last_name
    ,a.funded_date
    ,a.purchase_date
    ,a.miles
    ,a.duration
    ,a.sale_price
    ,a.sales_tax
    ,a.downpayment
FROM tDealer d
INNER JOIN tContact b ON d.contact_id = b.contact_id
INNER JOIN tContract a ON d.dealer_id = a.dealer_id
INNER JOIN tCompany c ON a.contract_id
WHERE c.program_id = 55
GROUP BY d.dealer_id
    ,account_no
    ,VIN
    ,first_name
    ,last_name
    ,funded_date purchase_date
    ,miles
    ,duration
    ,sale_price
    ,sales_tax
    ,downpayment
```

Comment: look at the last join. Notice anything missing?

Comment: `Join tCompany c ON a.contract_id = <what>` You need to connect a.contract_id to c somehow.

Comment: why on earth are you grouping in that select?

Comment: Add `= c.contract_id` to Last join `INNER JOIN tCompany c ON a.contract_id`, so it would become `INNER JOIN tCompany c ON a.contract_id = c.contract_id`

Comment: please first read your query carefully and the error text; Then if you can not help yourself ask help from us.

Answer (score 0):

Last join is incomplete "INNER JOIN tCompany c ON a.contract_id"
It should have a join with  tCompany if your tCompany  table has contract_id.